# Erlang net_kernel fails to start node (nodistribution)

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I am new to Erlang and RabbitMQ.

I have a node on RabbitMQ on CentOS which I had to reset to restart the message queues. Ever since the restart, the Erlang refuses to start the node. There was an erlang_vm corrupted error that was fixed with a rabbit remove and restart. I've tried net_kerlnel start in erlang shell but it fails.

```
[root@directadmin ~]# erl
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
1> node().
nonode@nohost
2> net_kernel:start([rabbit, shortnames]).
{error, 
    {{shutdown,
         {failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}},
     {child,undefined,net_sup_dynamic,
         {erl_distribution,start_link,[[rabbit,shortnames]]},
         permanent,1000,supervisor,
         [erl_distribution]}}}
3>
=INFO REPORT==== 26-Jan-2017::18:58:36 ===
Protocol: "inet_tcp": the name rabbit@directadmin seems to be in use by another Erlang node
```

I've noticed that someone else had a similar issue and they cited that fixing rule set in iptables resolved their issue. I am not sure how that is done. I've tried `service iptables restart` but that didn't make any difference

```
http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2015-October/086270.html
```

When I try run `rabbitmqctl stop_app` I get this error

```
[root@directadmin ~]# rabbitmqctl stop_app
Stopping node rabbit@directadmin ...
Error: erlang_vm_restart_needed
```

When I try running 'rabbitmqctl stop' I get the vm corrupted error

```
[root@directadmin ~]# rabbitmqctl stop
Stopping and halting node rabbit@directadmin ...
Error: {badarg,[{io,format,
                [standard_error,
                 "Erlang VM I/O system is damaged, restart needed~n",[]],
                []},
            {rabbit_log,handle_damaged_io_system,0,
                        [{file,"src/rabbit_log.erl"},{line,110}]},
            {rabbit_log,with_local_io,1,
                        [{file,"src/rabbit_log.erl"},{line,95}]},
            {rabbit,'-stop_and_halt/0-after$^0/0-0-',0,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,434}]},
            {rabbit,stop_and_halt,0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,431}]},
            {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                 [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,187}]}]}
```

Comment: here `rabbit@directadmin seems to be in use by another Erlang node` you are trying to use this `rabbit@directadmin` node name that is already running ( the rabbitmq node)

I didn't get what are you trying to do :(

Comment: @Gabriele thanks for the message. I was originally trying to restart the node as the running node was not functioning properly. When I try to stop the app I get an error that erlang vm restart is needed. I updated the error above in my post.

Comment: Do you have space in your disk?

Comment: @Gabriele I did not. Deleted log files from /var/log and performed a clean reinstall of erlang and Rabbit once again. It works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disk was full maybe due to the errors being written to log files. I deleted logs that occupied the most space in `var/log` and then ran `yum erase erlang` followed by a clean reinstall of erlang and rabbitmq. This resolved the issue. Thank you everyone for your contribution!

Answer (score 2):

You need `rabbitmqctl stop`, not just `rabbitmqctl stop_app`.

According to [the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html), `stop_app` "stops the RabbitMQ application, leaving the Erlang node running", while `stop` "stops the Erlang node on which RabbitMQ is running".

Comment: thanks for your message. I tried that as well and that's when it gives me the vm corrupted error. I updated this error in my post.

Comment: he got this error: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pull/768/files#diff-c239108d0df2581bd5ee38eb1f9e9bb0R112 ! first time I see it!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is coming from the fact that epmd is not started.
You need to start epmd manually or to by providing a node name when launching erl. This not specific to rabbitmq distribution.

http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-8.0/erts-8.0/doc/html/epmd.html